# Trying to install dataiku on ubuntu 18.04 and got a list of error

Tags: apt, java

This is the output I received after trying to install dataiku on ubuntu

```
 Creating data directory: DATA_DIR
[+] Saving installation log to /home/jp/DATA_DIR/run/install.log
[*] Could not find suitable version of Java
[+] Checking required dependencies
+ Detected OS distribution : ubuntu 18.04
+ Checking required packages...
*** Error: package nginx not found
*** Error: package unzip not found
*** Error: package zip not found
*** Error: package default-jre-headless not found
*** Error: package python2.7 not found
*** Error: package libpython2.7 not found
*** Error: package libgfortran3 not found
*** Error: package libgomp1 not found
** Error: package libgomp1 not found

[-] Dependency check failed
[-] You can install required dependencies with:
[-]    sudo -i "/home/jp/dataiku-dss-5.0.5/scripts/install/install-deps.sh"
[-] You can also disable this check with the -n installer flag
```

Not sure what to do with this.  where can I find these packages?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The message says:

```
[-] You can install required dependencies with:
[-]    sudo -i "/home/jp/dataiku-dss-5.0.5/scripts/install/install-deps.sh"
```

So run

```
sudo -i "/home/jp/dataiku-dss-5.0.5/scripts/install/install-deps.sh"
```

Answer (score 0):

so after my initial panic, I googled the packages and figured out how to install them for my version of Ubuntu.  After I install them all, the dataiku install worked